# Multiple states in Kanban board columns

Tags: tfs, agile, kanban

I have a Kanban board for my team in Team Foundation Server (TFS), but it's getting annoying with all our columns. Is there a way we can use multiple states for one column? And how do I set a state for the "done" column when splitting the column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way we can use multiple states for one column? and how do i set a state for the Done column when splitting em??

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such way we can use multiple states for one column since after update TFS to 2013.

There is a [User Voice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5589316-allow-multiple-complete-meta-state-mapping-in-tfs) wish the feature back, but that site is not currently active.

And I got the reply from MS team:

> **This is by design**.  We have work on our backlog to improve this
> experience as part of work item customization on VSO but that's
> another release away.  There are no workarounds and this will not be
> in QU5.

If it important for you, you can submit a new user voice on our UserVoice site

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22

which is our main forum for product suggestions. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps Server.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I just submited the feature request.